# Push Xcode Project to BitBucket

Tags: xcode, git, repository, bitbucket

[image]

I'm trying to push my local code from my new ios project to BitBucket.

I kept getting:

> An Unknown error occurred.

I double check the credentials to my BitBucket account that linked to Xcode is correct.

[image]

---

## Questions

**How would one go about and debug this further?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode has problems with uppercase letters in Bitbucket repository names. Name your Bitbucket repository `seafood` instead of `Seafood` and you should be able to create the remote Bitbucket repository.

Comment: Ok. I’ll try that. That weird.